# Click a href button which has onclick javascript attribute

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click a href link like this below;

```
<span class="clearForm">
<a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('form'),{'j_idt686':'j_idt686'},'');return false" class="btn btn-sm NSWbtn3">
Update</a>
</span>
```

I can catch the link with using css selector. But click function is not running because of onclick javascript call. How can I click on this link?

```
upd_button = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a.btn.btn-sm.NSWbtn3")
upd_button.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting that the `onclick()` is not running. Let's try using a different selector type and see if that helps.

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Update')]").click()
```

Comment: Thanks @Christine. I tried this one but no luck : (  Another link is clicked with this way not mine. When I try arguments[1].click();  nothing happened.

Comment: Interesting. instead of `find_element_by_css_selector`, could you try `find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Update')]").click()` ?

Comment: It worked! Could you post this one then I can check as an answer. Thank you very much. You are the man!

Comment: @Jack that's great news, happy to help. I've updated my answer with the proper solution.